# how can I add a special first item in wp7 listbox?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

The listbox has a datatemplate, but I want add a special item to the listbox, which can not be processed by the datatemplate. How can I do this?

Comment: What's the reason why you want to do this? Maybe there is another easier solution...

Comment: What do you mean "which can not be processed by the datatemplate"? Does that mean the existing item template of the listbox and the item you are trying to insert newly are not compatible? If so why dont you use DataTemplateSelector (http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector)

Comment: Note that WP7 does not support development in WPF it supports Silverlight and XNA.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [`CompositeCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx) at your disposal (- sorry if you don't -) you could try to work with that.

```
private void ListBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var specialItem = new ListBoxItem()
    {
        Content = "Very special item.",
        FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold
    };
    var collectionContainer = new CollectionContainer()
    {
        Collection = MyCollection
    };
    var composite = new CompositeCollection();
    composite.Add(specialItem);
    composite.Add(collectionContainer);
    (sender as ListBox).ItemsSource = composite;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Listbox has a reasonable number of items, you can set the `AlternationCount` of the Listbox to something greater than your item count, and use a DataTrigger on the ListBoxItem's `AlternationIndex` to do something special such as switching templates if it's equal to 0